# Cant use complex types from WSDL on BPEL module

Tags: netbeans, xsd, wsdl, bpel

I am creating a BPEL module on Netbeans (OpenESB 2.3); for my operation I need to import complex types from the WS involved in the process, so I import an External WSDL document prior to creating the module.

The problem is that, complex types embedded in the WSDL definition are not available to choose from when creating an operation in the output WSDL file for my BPEL module. I am forced to extract the XS bit of the WSDL to an external file, which is kind of annoying and redundant.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: I would actually call it a good pattern to move schema definition out from the WSDL into a separate file.

Comment: Okay, but since it is already defined as an embedded xsd in my WebService, it would be reduntant. I know it's not that much effort to manually move it but when you have 100+ WebServices it can get a bit annoying.